# Proof using the axioms of arithmetic and order.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume X is an ordered field, i.e. it is a set with binary operations "+" and "·" and a binary relation "≦" such that the axioms of arithmetic and the axioms of order are satisfied. Using only the axioms of arithmetic and order, show that if x,y ∈ X satisfy 0 ≦ x, 0 ≦ y and x ≦ y, then x·x ≦ y·y.

Can you show me the complete proof and not just hints?

Comment: Leon: You've asked 10 questions now, but accepted no answers. We encourage users to accept an answer for each question asked if/when they find an answer to be helpful. You can accept one answer per question asked. To accept an answer, just click on the $\Large\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept; it turns green when you click on it, and you get $2$ reputation points for each answer you accept.

Answer (score 2):

Note the following:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
x+y &\geq& 0+y &\text{since }x\geq 0 \\
 &\geq& 0+0 &\text{since }y\geq 0 \\
 &=& 0.
\end{array}$$
Also note
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
y-x &\geq& x-x &\text{since }y\geq x \\
 &=& 0.
\end{array}$$
Thus
$$(y-x)\cdot(y+x) = y\cdot y-x\cdot x \geq 0$$
and hence
$$y\cdot y \geq x\cdot x.$$